# What is the difference between the below queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table my_table (
     column_a integer not null,
     column_b integer not null,
     column_c varchar(50),
     primary key (column_a, column_b)
);
```

-- this one gives error

`Msg 8110, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Cannot add multiple PRIMARY KEY constraints to table '#my_table'.`

```
create table my_table (
     column_a integer primary key not null,
     column_b integer primary key not null,
     column_c varchar(50),
    );
```

What is the difference between the above 2 codes first one executes correctly but latter doesn't?
but both are creating the multiple primary keys ?

Comment: Only one primary key allowed per table.You can opt for a composite primary key which you have done in your first query

Answer (score 3):

The first one is a composite key, which means that the combination of two columns must be unique. Your second one, on the other hand, is trying to create two separate primary keys which is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one primary key per table. This acts as a unique identifier for your table, so of course it would fail.

Answer (score 1):

In the first query multiple fields has been assigned to a primary key as you can have multiple fields in your primary key, but in the second query it is trying to create multiple primary keys which is not possible.